# How to add MouseListener to a table model

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, defaulttablemodel

I have a JTable. When a user clicks on a cell another JTable is created that shows the data for the whole row of that cell, in a column format (ie the row is converted to a column).

This happens when the user clicks but its a bit irritating to happen every time so I want to make it only on a double click.

The problem is that the getSelection method of the table only takes a addListSelectionListener method and not a MouseListener. How can I do what I want?

Here is the code:

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                    DefaultTableModel newModel = new DefaultTableModel();
                    String rowName = "Row: " + selectedRow;
                    newModel.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{rowName});
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.getModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                        newModel.addRow(new Object[]{table.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRow, i)});
                    }
                    JTable newTable = new JTable(newModel) {
                        /**
                         * 
                         */
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                        @Override
                        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                            return new Dimension(140, 240);
                        }
                    };

                    // Apply any custom renderers and editors
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, new JScrollPane(newTable),
                        rowName, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

> This happens when the user clicks but its a bit irritating to happen every time so I want to make it only on a double click

You use a `MouseListener`, not a ListSelectionListener. You would check the Mouse event for a click count of 2.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a MouseLister](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more information and working examples.

Also, a double click will start the editor by default so you want to make sure the cell is not editable. So you may need to override the `isCellEditable(...)` method of the table.